# O Delphi possui coletor de lixo?

Tags: delphi, memória, gerenciamento-de-memória, garbage-collector, object-pascal

O Delphi possui coletor de lixo automático? De que maneira ele funciona. Caso não exista, que ferramentas podem fazer isso?

Comment: no código do programa eu sempre coloco `ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown:= True;`pra ter uma noção de e sempre deixar o código limpo.

Comment: @Artur_Indio, acabei de ler sobre o comando e ele é ótimo. Muito obrigado :D

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Não existe no sentido mais aceito de [*garbage collector*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29), embora dê para questionar este conceito. Delphi é uma linguagem de gerenciamento de memória manual com algumas facilidades na biblioteca, semelhante ao que se usa em C++ moderno, para quem conhece esta linguagem.

Vários tipos existentes na biblioteca padrão possuem um controle próprio da alocação da memória, em geral, através de um contador de referências que é uma técnica de coleta de lixo, mas que alguns não consideram exatamente um GC. *Strings* e *arrays* dinâmicos são exemplos de tipos que usam esta técnica.

Outra forma é através do `TComponent`. Todos descendentes dele se "auto gerenciam", assim quando um objeto é destruído ele fica responsável por liberar os seus filhos. A soma das duas técnicas citadas e o uso de interfaces podem facilitar bastante o trabalho quando estruturas complexas de objetos são montadas. Além disto é possível fazer o controle explícito com `try-finally` de forma muito semelhante ao que ocorre em Java e C# quando quer explicitar que um recurso deve ser liberado, com a diferença que o Delphi pode liberar o recurso e a memória no mesmo momento.

A facilidade do [*reference counting*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting#Delphi) está disponível na biblioteca - implementando com interfaces - para ser usado com outros tipos que você deseje criar e ele seja necessário. A maioria dos tipos não precisam graças ao conceito de propriedade do objeto (só existe um proprietário).

Particularmente se a coleta do lixo é feita de forma automática sem intervenção do programador eu considero que de certa forma o Delphi tem um GC. É preciso deixar claro que a forma dele é por contagem de referência e não de rastreamento de referências (*tracing GC*). Oficialmente se diz que Delphi não é uma linguagem com GC, mas a biblioteca possui funcionalidade semelhante. Claro que no momento que você vai criar tipos, precisa se lembrar de cuidar do gerenciamento usando o que a biblioteca já oferece ou outra forma, mas o uso dos objetos passa ser gerenciado se usar o que está disponível.

Claro que é possível usar um GC rastreador se ele for absolutamente necessário mas não faz parte da linguagem - por isto não há muitas facilidades - ou da biblioteca padrão, você tem que providenciar toda infraestrutura dele. E não é aconselhável em quase nenhum caso.

Há uma experiência no site da Embarcadero (ou sei lá o nome que a empresa tem agora) para implementar o [GC Boehm](http://codecentral.embarcadero.com/Item/21646) que é um dos GCs mais simples que existe, quase sempre tão ineficiente que não vale o esforço quando existe outra forma de gerenciar a memória automaticamente.

A linguagem organiza a memória de forma que falta metadados para um GC mais moderno já que ela foi pensada para não usar um GC.

Ao contrário da crença popular, um GC moderno consegue gerenciar a memória de forma mais rápida que outras formas. Em *refcount* é necessário incrementar o contador, depois decrementar e verificar se chegou a zero, tudo isso pode ser preciso fazer de forma sincronizada (atômica) o que é bem caro de realizar. E pode ser necessário fazer uma coleta para evitar vazamento por referências cíclicas ou usar uma técnica que pode gerar falhas. Em GC a alocação da memória costuma ser apenas um incremento em um ponteiro de forma semelhante ao que ocorre na *stack* e não há custo para desalocar quando o objeto não mais é necessário. O problema do GC moderno é o retardamento da desalocação e isto traz algumas desvantagens:

- O momento da liberação de recursos não é determinístico e ferramentas auxiliares na linguagem são necessárias para garantir esta liberação no momento certo.
- Também é indeterminado o tempo que levará para fazer toda liberação. É verdade que outras formas de liberação de memória também não podem ter o tempo determinado mas assim como no GC, há acúmulo, a indeterminação fica maior.
- Como o GC precisa determinar o que é útil e o que é lixo e em algumas implementações precisa copiar dados, o processamento total para a liberação acaba sendo maior. Há exceções.

Para saber mais sobre implementações de GC o artigo da Wikipedia mostrado acima já é um bom começo. Lá tem recomendação de bons livros sobre o assunto.

No caso do Delphi a "falta de um GC" faz pouca diferença para a maioria dos usuários, principalmente porque ele costuma ser usado em um conjunto mais específico de problemas. Para quem faz as bibliotecas o trabalho extra de gerenciamento costuma ser um problema maior.

Outra questão é que implementar um GC decente é bem complexo enquanto implementar um mecanismo de contagem de referência é trivial.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Pascal/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score -3):

Não o Delphi não tem GC. O GC na minha concepção é a liberação automática de objetos alocados pelo programa por codigo gerado pelo compilador no executável. Codigo este que está à margem da execução principal, liberando o programador desta tarefa (de desalocar a memória préviamente alocada)

Exemplo : uma thread poderia executar o GC. Mas somente se o compilador gerasse codigo para registrar, em memória global, tudo que é alocado em tempo de execução, mas isso não é feito. o registro do que é alocado é somente feito para os tipos  :  Long strings, strings, dynamic arrays, variants e interfaces. E o motivo disso não ser feito para os outros tipos ou objetos é a queda de performance do executável, pois se a cada alocação de memória (e são muitas num executável) numa chamada de função fosse gerado codigo de registro de tudo que é alocado e a sua desalocação em momento inapropriado pela thread GC, a performance de execução teria uma queda e um custo na velocidade de execução.

O refCount que é usado para strings, arrays, variants e interfaces não pode ser considerado um GC, se fosse seu nome não seria refcount, mas GC.

O Delphi sempre foi uma linguagem intermediária no sentido de não ser nem de alto nível como o JAVA ou VB (que produz bytecode ao invés de codigo nativo) e nem de baixo nível como o Assembler que produz linguagem de máquina de altíssima velocidade de execução.

O Delphi está no meio, equiparável ao C, c++ (que também não tem GC)

A busca pela performance do executável juntamente com as características e padrões de linguagem adotados lá no inicio vindo do Pascal, Turbo Pascal e  Object Pascal fazem do Delphi uma linguagem sem GC, porém de alta performance e bem superior a seus pares  como VB e Java no que diz respeito a performance.

---

Senhores :

vejam esse estudo no link abaixo onde a pessoa faz um estudo detalhado sobre performance comparativa entre C#, Delphi Prism, Delphi 2009 e C++ Builder 2009.

E a conclusão é que o Delphi é superior em performance à essas 3 linguagens.

Infelizmente não tenho o mesmo estudo em comparação com o Java apenas para lhe satisfazer porque para mim não resta dúvida alguma do que postei, apenas não posso confirmar por estudos publicados.

E o que eu afirmei sobre o Delphi ser superior seria em Performance apenas, até poderia afirmar em relação a outros aspectos mas esperarei outros tópicos, pois a questão aqui era o GC.

Segue o link do estudo comparativo de performance :

http://www.ijcaonline.org/volume26/number1/pxc3874199.pdf

Conclusão do Estudo :

> 4.CONCLUSION
>
> In terms of response time, the fastest programming language is the Delphi 2009 and the slowest programming language is the C++ Builder 2009. Although the managed language C# and the Delphi Prism are powerful in terms of code density, they are weak in terms of memory consumption and response time.
>
> The Delphi 2009 is the most powerful programming language both in terms of memory consumption and response time

---

O contador de referência (refCount) implementado pela Embarcadero no Delphi tem objetivo de otimização de consumo de memória e performance no acesso a mesma (alocação e desalocação) uma vez que o custo de alocação de memória no HEAP por API do windows é alto em termos de ciclos de CPU utilizado. Desta forma o compilador aloca um grande quantidade de memória na inicialização do executável e esta memória vai sendo consumida em pedaços distribuidos para as várias alocações que são feitas durante a execução do módulo executável.

Neste modelo de contagem de referência, um pedaço de memória alocado por exemplo por uma WideString ou array dinâmico não é obtida diretamente de uma API do Windows mas é feito um pedido ao gerenciador de memória do Delphi FastMM que através do algoritimo RefCount se encarrega de entregar um pedaço de memória à string por um custo baixo em termos de ciclos de CPU utilizados.

O RefCount é um excelente otimizador de uso de memória, a não utilização do mesmo resultaria em duplicação de memória desnecessária. Já com sua utilização a memória é otimizada,

considere o exemplo abaixo :

Var

```
a, b : String;
```

Begin

```
a := 'asdqwe';

b := a;
```

End;

Com o RefCount não há duplicação. A alocação é feita primeiro para A que conta 1 no RefCount. Na instrução abaixo não há uma alocação nova de memória, não há copias, B simplesmente aponta para o mesmo endereço de A e o RefCount de A é incrementado em 1 resultando 2.

Na desalocação é feita o decremento dos contadores de referência. Quando o Contador chegar a zero a memória volta para o FASTMM para que seja usada novamente por novas alocações.

Conclusão :
O RefCount é um excelente otimizador de recursos de memória além de proporcionar velocidade no acesso a mesma, mas não pode ser considerado um Garbage Collector como alguns academicistas ou "programadores de lousa" querem fazer crer.

Referências :

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Memory_Management

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Internal_Data_Formats

---

Garbage Collection (ou garbage collector)

É uma estratégia para automação do gerenciamento de memória onde o compilador gera codigo para desalocação de forma automática liberando o programador da tarefa de desalocação (ou finalização de um objeto).

Vantagens

Retira a preocupação do programador em ter que liberar a memória alocada, provendo sempre uma memória em que não há vazamentos.

O problema é que a desalocação em muitos casos não é feita no momento em que o programa se desfaz da variável ou objeto em memória e isso traz desvantagens como queda de performance na execução do aplicativo, como pode ser visto abaixo;

Destanvangens

Apesar de ter a vantagem citada no primeiro parágrafo ele possui desvantagens. São processos que consomem recursos computacionais para decidir quais partes da memória podem ser liberadas, enquanto no gerenciamento manual esse consumo é mínimo. Outro ponto negativo é que o momento em que o objeto é realmente desalocado não é determinístico, o que pode acarretar na variação do tempo de execução de algoritmo em partes aleatórias.

A queda de performance de uma aplicação pode ser tal forma que àquelas que necessitam de uma performance superior teriam que suspender temporariamente o GC para não interferir no processamento. No .NET 4.6 já há diretivas ou métodos (TryStartNoGCRegion e EndNoGCRegion) para bloquear o GC de operar em um determinado trecho de codigo.

Referências :
http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coletor_de_lixo_%28inform%C3%A1tica%29

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: O que você diz que deixaria lento é justamente o que o Delphi faz. O problema do GC é outro. Fora que você está dando opinião sobre uma ser superior à outra linguagem. Se vai afirmar isto, prove.

Comment: Prezado não preciso provar o que eu digo sobre performance de execução de uma linguagem em comparação com outra, quem já programou nessas 4 linguagens como eu já programei, sabe que o que falo tem fundamento. Será que eu realmente preciso provar que o compilador Java produz bytecode e o Delphi produz codigo nativo ? Mas se voce quiser eu trago artigos aqui.

Comment: Aqui colocamos respostas objetivas. Se quer colocar uma resposta subjetiva, ok, mas você tem que fundamentar o que está dizendo, caso contrário a resposta está errada. Eu programei nessas linguagens e sei que não tem fundamento. Você tem que provar porque uma é superior à outra, você afirmou isto. E fui claro que o problema é este. A parte objetiva, ok, a parte subjetiva precisa se sustentação, não basta sua opinião.

Comment: Hmmm programei muitos anos em Delphi e programo há vários anos em Java e, ao contrário do que você disse, acho que o que você fala não tem fundamento. Não creio que Delphi seja superior a Java ou outras linguagens com GC nas quais programei muitos anos também. A performance, por sua vez, pode ser melhor em um ou em outro considerando exemplos específicos que por sua vez podem não interessar na maioria dos cenários (ou pelos exemplos não serem válidos no mundo real ou pela diferença de performance não ser relevante no mundo real).

Comment: **Nota do moderador:** Você sempre pode editar suas postagens (perguntas ou respostas), tem um link pra isso abaixo dela, antes da área dos comentários. Sempre que precisar complementar ou corrigir uma resposta, use esse recurso. Use comentários para discutir outros comentários. E só poste uma nova resposta caso seja mesmo uma resposta (diferente) à pergunta lá do topo. Espero que tenha ficado mais claro que parte da confusão que houve aqui foi por você não ter entendido o sistema, o que é normal para usuários novos. Recomendo uma leitura do [tour] e da [help], e fico à disposição se precisar.

Comment: A segunda parte na verdade foge do escopo da pergunta. Ele existe em função de uma afirmação na resposta original que não pode ser comprovada. Inclusive o texto apresentado não prova nada. Ele não mostra como os testes são feitos e chega a conclusões estapafúrdias, principalmente porque não dá para comparar linguagens, nem mesmo implementações de linguagens. E mal dá para comparar algoritmos implementados em linguagens diferentes. Programadores experientes sabem disto. Mas se alguém tiver informação relevante que não é isto, é só apresentar.

Comment: Amigo voce desqualifica textos sérios, quando coloquei minha resposta, você me a desqualificou pedindo provas, eu as forneci, voce desqualifica as provas novamente, talvez pela sua ignorância e desconhecimento do que é codigo gerenciado e codigo nativo, ou mesmo preconceito com o Delphi, mas paro aqui, pode falar o que quiser, vá enganando os outros aí com sua sapiência, não respondo mais.

Bye

Comment: Desculpe Claudio, não quero criticar a sua resposta, mas "C++ Builder 2009" não é linguagem (ou eu entendi mal a sua resposta). Eu não entendo muito disto, mas ao meu pouco conhecimento fatores que fazem a diferença na performance são compiladores e APIs usadas, me corrija se eu estiver enganado. Agora acho que a linguagem em si pouco afetará a performance (talvez eu esteja falando um monte de besteiras), ao menos é o que parece que realmente afeta.

Comment: Você está coberto de razão Guilherme, talvez eu tenha me expressado de forma imperfeita, o compilador é que produz um executável performático e não a linguagem em si. E no caso o compilador do Delphi o qual estavamos tratando, é o que produz código executável mais performático dentre os que tratamos, por este produzir codigo nativo de máquina enquanto outros não o fazem.

Quanto a C++ Builder não ser uma linguagem eu discordo mas não entendi muito bem as suas razões pelo qual voce acredita que ele não seja uma linguagem.

Comment: Boa tarde @ClaudioFerreira , meu conhecimento é limitado, porém até aonde sei `C++ Builder` se refere ao IDE e talvez as APIs adicionais usadas, semelhante ao QT. Eu acredito que a linguagem é "C++ normal" (não sei dizer se eles usam o formato c++11), a unica coisa que muda talvez seja o "compilador" e as bibliotecas, mas a linguagem em si é a mesma. Ou seja `C++ Bulder` pode ser um IDE e uma biblioteca, mas acredito que não seja uma linguagem "fork".  Até mais :)

Comment: Se voce conseguir levar o codigo feito nele para ser compilado e executado em Unix por exemplo no compilador GCC, estará programando em C++ Puro, já se isso não for possivel voce está programando na linguagem C++ Builder.

Tudo depende da maneira como vai codificar considerando as variadas plataformas que a liguagem C++ suporta.

Comment: @ClaudioFerreira Boa noite, se ver por estes pontos de vista então `C++ Builder` não é linguagem e sim um SDK, assim como o QT. Talvez eles vendam essa imagem de "linguagem" só para dizer que é uma inovação, não posso afirmar, mas ainda sim tudo leva a crer que seja um SDK.

Comment: De forma alguma é considerado um SDK. O C++ Builder é muito mais que isso : incorpora em sua IDE o conceito de RAD (Rapid Application Development) onde componentes são reutilizados extensivamente, um compilador robusto e otimizado para Windows, gerenciador de memória FastMM e um conjunto imenso de componentes acessórias que uma aplicação comercial não fica sem, como componentes de acesso a banco de dados, Programação MultiTier, WebServices, enfim, não vou colocar tudo aqui até porque não conheço tudo, .....

Comment: o C++ Builder é um produto completo e jamais pode ser chamado de SDK pois seria reduzir um maravilhoso produto com inúmeros recursos a um simples biblioteca de acesso ao Windows por exemplo. Não é.

Comment: Boa noite @ClaudioFerreira , Então se for assim o QT também não pode ser chamado de SDK, pois ele também é completo, possuindo bibliotecas próprias, sendo cross-platform, cross-builder, tem IDE e interage com diversas APIs de sistemas operacionais diferentes. Então por causa disto o QT agora é uma linguagem de programação?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22266/discussion-between-claudio-ferreira-and-guilherme-nascimento).

Comment: Performance somente é superior em 32 bits. Em 64 o code gen do delphi não é otimizado

Comment: Verdade @EProgrammerNotFound

Comment: Seu exemplo com widestring esta errado. Widestring sempre gera nova copia com o operador atribuicao. Veja o disassembly panel. Os casos que nao geram eh se passar por referencia ou const. Seu exemplo estaria correto se vc tivesse utilizado string, ansistrig ou unicodestring

Comment: Fato ! esse é o único tipo string que não é Referenciado. Não reparei mas na página da Embarcadero tinha o seguinte comentário :

"WideString is composed of WideChars like UnicodeString, but is not reference counted. "

Corrigi o exemplo. Obrigado pela observação.